# Character selection layout with DLC

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

From the images on [Smash Wiki](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Character_selection_screen) I can see the following:

- With no DLC purchased, the characters are laid out in four rows: two rows of 12 (top and bottom) and two rows of 13 (in the middle).
- With all DLC purchased, the characters are laid out in five rows: two rows of 12 (top two) and three rows of 11 (bottom three).

How are the characters laid out when only some of the characters are purchased?  How many characters can be purchased before the layout changes to five rows?

Comment: Why do you want to know this and how can it help someone else?

Comment: It will lay out as many characters as it can on one page, then spill over to the next one.